# PHP & MySQL Timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, timezone

My hosting environment (PHP & MySQL) is on GoDaddy, and their timezones are by default America/Denver for both PHP & MySQL.

I currently have a website, and the PHP scripts have

```
 //Set timezone
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

On all scripts. (It's in a config file that is always included)

I believe that settings my PHP to date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); is the correct thing to do for UK users.

However, I'm coming unstuck with regards to MySQL.

Sometimes, one of my PHP scripts Will store a date/time in MySQL Server and expressively tell MySQL what the timestamp is

PHP -> Store "2020-01-01 15:00:00" -> DB

If I open phpMyAdmin and view the stored information, I can see that 2020-01-01 15:00:00 is stored.

Although now, I believe that that's actually 2020-01-01 15:00:00 in America/Denver time - is my thinking on this correct?

Other times, I use to have a MySQL field with a DEFAULT value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

I let MySQL Generate the current TIMESTAMP for an insert when i want it to be the current time, however, what I expected to be saved in the UK format, is in American/Denver time - So I may run an insert at "2020-01-01 13:00:00" in the UK, but in MySQL, the result stores are "2020-01-01 06:00:00" (Because MySQL Generated the timestamp, not PHP)

My questions are, Am I right in thinking that to fix this little mess; I need to:

1: Update all historic PHP generated timestamps that are currently stored and rewind them 7 hours, so they are in the server's timezone

2: When connecting to MySQL with PHP, run this query: SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'; then run any and all further queries, SELECTS, INSERTS, etc
-this will then show me the UK version of the stored timestamps if I select them
-this will automatically wind any new PHP generated timestamps back to the MySQL server timezone when inserted

Comment: The datetime format above is not MySQL datetime format, look like you are storing datetime as text/varchar

Comment: You are correct, my example is in my natural UK tongue lol - My field types are TIMESTAMP. So in actual fact it is stored 2020-01-01 15:00:00 -  I will edit my question to reflect this

Comment: I'm not sure simply rewinding it 7 hours would give correct results, considering DST.

Comment: Tip: Store your database dates/times in UTC. Convert back to the user's locale in the application or presentation layer. This makes your database zone agnostic, and you won't be subject to the often arbitrary political whims of whatever zone you're hosting this in.

Comment: @tadman   Doesn't the TIMESTAMP field internally store all data as UTC anyway?

Comment: It's stored as epoch time, which opens you up to huge 2038 bug issues, but it's interpreted according to the configured time zone, which causes other problems.